# What is the best way to design a sql query storage in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, design-patterns, structure

I've encountered a somewhat difficult design problem:

I'm currently writing an application that frequently requests data from a Postgres database. Some of these requests of course need parameters, some don't. Some have the same return type, some don't.

Now since I've started this project to essentially learn how to structure code efficiently and especially modular, I've come across the question on how to manage the storage of all these requests.

My current approach was the following:

I've set up an enum of enums, where each of these sub-enums implements a different interface, where each of these interfaces declares a method stub. These stubs differ in parameters and return type.

It looks something like this:

```java
public enum Queries {
  ;
  public enum Queries_TypeA implements TypeAInterface {

    SOME_QUERY_A {
      @Override
      public double execute(String id, Date date) {

      }
    },

    SOME_OTHER__QUERY_A {
      @Override
      public double execute(String id, Date date) {

      }
    };
  },
  public enum Queries_TypeB implements TypeBInterface {

     SOME_QUERY_B {
      @Override
      public String execute() {

      }
    },

    SOME_OTHER__QUERY_B {
      @Override
      public String execute() {

      }
    };
  }
}
```

So if I wanted to get the results of, e.g. SOME_QUERY_A, I'd just do the following:

```java
double result = Queries.QueriesTypeA.SOME_QUERY_A.execute("0", date1, date2);
```

This is just a small excerpt. I haven't fully implemented it yet and that's why I'm asking this question. In the overwritten methods, the actual query would happen and the result would be parsed and then returned, but as this is not important here, I didn't specify the implementation.

In reality, there would be a lot more of enums, sub enums and interfaces.

Is there a better solution to this (I'm sure there is), especially regarding scalability and modularity? 
Or is there some kind of state-of-the-art way on how to handle this type of problem?

I'm really looking forward to opinions and ideas.

Regards, 
adurx

Comment: You want to invent something like `NamedQuery`? https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named

Comment: Maybe you should start by implementing the specific queries you need and use them in your code and then once you get a feel for what you need and how you use the queries and results it could be time to re-factor and design common functionality

Comment: Thanks @Sascha, this looks promising. But I'm using JDBC, and I guess that this is not compatible, right? (Sorry for not tagging, will tag now)

Comment: It's just Annotations, so it ist pure Java, all you have to do is add the persistence-api to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into [Spring JDBC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate), especially JDBCTemplate. It's a powerful API that already provides the abstractions you've modeled and much more. That would eliminate much of the boilerplate without introducing the learning curve and complexity that comes with an object-relational mapper (JPA).

Answer (score 1):

Generally when interacting with DBs from java, there are 2 main ways to do it:

1. The ORM style. Use hibernate or some other JPA implementation. The notion here is that you should think about the database as an implementation detail; the JPA is really its own language (similar but not quite the same as SQL) and its function is to store and let you query for objects. It has a number of downsides (you don't (easily) get the full power of SQL at your finger tips, the abstraction is leaky, and performance tweaking is tricky), but at least it's DB engine independent.
2. Go straight SQL. You might think: Yeah that's what JDBC is for, but.. no. JDBC is a low-level glue library which is intentionally ugly and inconvenient to use. That's by design; the purpose of JDBC is to be the lowest level, offer-all-capabilities-in-as-uniform-a-fashion-as-possible. It is designed by committee, the committee being oracle and major DB vendors. It's like the assembler of DB languages; You're not really supposed to use it directly. There are, fortunately, various light abstraction layers built on top of it which still give you straight SQL access but with a much nicer API. There are a few big players in this space, but I suggest you look at either [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) or [JDBI](https://jdbi.org/)

Your question appears to indicate you wish to head for the straight JDBC option. Not really how to do this. JDBI has solutions for the problem you're facing, and I'm pretty sure JOOQ does too. The general gist of what they go for is that you make a POJO describing the resultset (the X in: SELECT X FROM ....) such that you can iterate over nice POJO instead, and/or that you annotate methods with the query that powers it, and then let the framework (so, JDBI or JOOQ) generate the JDBC-based code to make queries automatically from there.

In short: Check oot JDBI or JOOQ.